# How can I remove the Kindle ad on the frontpage of amazon.com using Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, advertisements

When I open the amazon.com webpage, they always display this huge add for the Kindle device. It literally takes half of the page and I don't want it.

I wonder if there is some kind of extension that could remove it.

Google Chrome Browser only.

I am not looking for an Ad Blocker or a Flash blocker - just something that will filter out a section from the Amazon home page.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following custom filter to Ad Block Plus:

```
amazon.com###center1
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 4.0, which is [currently in beta](http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/), has extensions.

Adblock extension for Chrome 4.0:

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom

Flashblock extensions for Chrome 4.0:

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cdngiadmnkhgemkimkhiilgffbjijcie
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gofhjkjmkpinhpoiabjplobcaignabnl

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - I am not looking for a general answer for blocking ads
This is a section of the amazon front page, not an Ad from a network - it's being pushed by Amazon themselves. Also I don't want to block all flash content, I just want to filter this section.
I would appreciate if someone has a precise answer to this question

Comment: @bengrine - you can (at least in the Firefox version) block individual URLs with AdBlock.

Answer (score 1):

You can use adblock plus and not sign up for any subscriptions, it won't automaticaly block all ads, you can then right click on ads you don't like and click "Adblock Plus: Block Image"